# Native applications bundle ids in watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos, bundle-identifier

I am just looking for the native watchOS applications bundle ids.

For example:

for iPhone: **"com.apple.news"** and what is for Watch: ???

I tried **"com.apple.news.watchkitapp"** which doesn't work.
Maybe someone know how to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help you.

iPhone app bundle ID: com.companyName.myapp

Watch app bundle ID: com.companyName.myapp.watchkitapp

Watch extension bundle ID: com.companyName.myapp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

Comment: Thank you for your help 
I already tried that, in this case it didn't work for native watchOS applications, but really appreciate your help!